# Is it possible to proxy `ScrapeConfig` targets?

Tags: prometheus-operator

I discovered Prometheus Operator [`ScrapeConfig`](https://prometheus-operator.dev/docs/user-guides/scrapeconfig/?#use-scrapeconfig-to-scrape-an-external-target) CRD.

I have a working Prometheus deployment that requires a proxy to generate ID tokens to authenticate requests to an external (Google Cloud Run) service. The token must have a per-target audience:

```
- job_name: foo
  scheme: http
  proxy_url: http://proxy:7777
  http_sd_configs:
  - refresh_interval: 1m
    url: http://service-discovery:8080
```

In this case, the Service Discovery endpoint is **not** authenticated but targets described by the endpoint **must** be authenticated.

Prometheus provides only limited auth options and the use of a proxy provides a general-purpose solution.

I'm porting the solution to Kubernetes but it appears that it's not possible to configure `ScrapeConfig` to proxy its requests (neither to the Service Discovery endpoint not to the resulting targets).

Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

No.

[Issue #5966: Enable `ScrapeConfig` to use (discovery|target) proxies](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/5966)